# python tornado how to get id of a edge

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I have a web application that runs on flask web framework. Flask couldn't answer application requirements anymore. So we have decided to migrate tornado. 
I need to handle below two request.

```
 /entry GET Method
 /entry/id GET Method
```

1. When first request called it must return authenticated entry.
2. When second request called it must return the entry whose entry_id
   is id

Is there a different nice solution to handle above request except my solution. The solution i have found it creates cyclomatic complexity.

```
def get(self):
     id = self.request.path.split('/')[-1]
     if id is None:
         #return authenticated user
     else:
         #return the user whose entry_id is id
```

Note: I am looking a solution like this:

```
@rest_user.route('/user', methods=['GET'])
     #some code
@rest_user.route('/user/<user_id>', methods=['GET'])
     #some code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analogous arrangement in Tornado uses two handler classes (perhaps with a common base class for shared methods):

```
class AuthedUserHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...

class UserHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, user_id):
        ...

app = Application([
    ('/user', AuthedUserHandler),
    ('/user/(.*)', UserHandler),
])
```